# Clojure docstring for libraries/namespaces

Tags: clojure, documentation, docstring

How to add docstrings and/or comments to Clojure libaries/namespaces as a whole, i.e. not just to specific functions within the namespace?

I've noticed that the clojure source uses `(comment ...)` in some places to do this ([example](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/parallel.clj)), is that recommended?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add it to the `ns` declaration:

```
(ns ^{:author "mikera"
      :doc "My awesome library"}
  foo.bar.core)
```

The example you link to does that too - so not sure if this is what you mean? But I think it's the most "standard" - it will get picked up by documentation systems such as [Codox](https://github.com/hugoduncan/codox) and [Autodoc](https://github.com/tomfaulhaber/autodoc/).

Comment: Note that `ns` is [defined](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns) to take a docstring as an optional second argument.  This answer is equivalent to [kotarak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11611325/122762).

Answer (score 48):

You can add a docstring to any namespace in the `ns` form.

```
(ns my.name.space
  "Very cool namespace doing this and that."
  (:require other.cool.stuff))
```

Comment: Indeed. And if Codox refuses to make it appear in the html files, try a `lein clean`.